# Программа не выводит больше 5 элементов массива. язык С

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n,i;
    double mas[n];  
    printf("\n Vvedite razmer massiva\n"); 
    scanf("%f",&n); 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
        mas[i] = (double)(rand()%10000)/100; 
        printf("%f ", mas[i]);  
        };
   getch();
}
```

1 выводит, 2 выводит, 3 выводит, 4 выводит, 5 выводит, любое число больше 5 вводишь - выводит всё равно только 5

Comment: А можно внести предложение: за имена переменных типа "mas",  или промпты типа "Vvedite" банить нахрен, не глядя?

Comment: @klopp, думаю нет. Не у всех хорошо с английским, и вывод русского текста на консоль под Windows не всегда простая задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Его нужно проинициализировать. Например так:

```
#define ARRAY_MAX 666
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n,i;
    double mas[ARRAY_MAX]; 
    for (i=0;i<ARRAY_MAX;i++) mas[i]=0.0; 
    printf("\n Vvedite razmer massiva\n"); 
    scanf("%f",&n); 
    if (n>ARRAY_MAX) n=ARRAY_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
        mas[i] = (double)(rand()%10000)/100; 
        printf("%f ", mas[i]);  
        };
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Выводит 666 элементов, а не n...

Comment: Ну если вам нужно больше увеличьте ARRAY_MAX, там же проверка стоит. Это статический массив, а не динамический.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<ARRAY_MAX;i++) mas[i]=0.0; ` - это лишнее.

Comment: Лучше на всякий случай перестраховаться.

Answer (score 0):

Вы при объявлении массива `double mas[n]` используете неинициализированную переменную `n`.

Я так понял - вы хотите динамически создавать массив количество элементов в котором вводит пользователь. Для динамического выделения памяти используйте функцию `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    double *parray = NULL;
    printf("\n Vvedite razmer massiva\n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // Allocate memory
    parray = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    if (!parray) {
        printf("Not enough memory. Sorry :(\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Fill array elements
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n * sizeof(double); i += sizeof(double), j++) {
        *(parray + i) = (double)(rand()%10000)/100;
        printf("%f ", *(parray + i));
    }
    free(parray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сохранять размер int'а в переменной, да ещё с именем `double_size` - это что-то странное...  

`*(parray + i)` - можно же `parray[i]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил, сп

Comment: Я вот всё равно не понимаю, чем `malloc(n * size_of_double)` лучше чем `malloc(n * sizeof(double))`.

Comment: @Qwertiy тем что не нужно вызывать функцию много раз, в том числе в цикле с потенциально большим количеством итераций?

Comment: sizeof - это оператор, а не функция. Более того, его значение - это константа, известная при компиляции. Я понимаю, что в варианте с её помещением в переменную, компилятор всё равно догадается подставить константу, но смысл?

Comment: разумно, обновил ответ

Comment: Вот в подобных случаях крайне жаль, что в невозможно привести `отформатированный фрагментик кода` в комментарии. / Но, не делать же ради такой мелочи ответ, тем более не относящийся напрямую к вопросу.

Comment: @avp можете фрагмент кода залить на gist и приложить ссылку